# Python: finding the index of a list into a list of list

Tags: python, list, loops

I am a beginner in python and facing difficulty while searching the index of a list into another list of list. I have two list of lists X and X_test. Sample given below:

```
X = [[5 1 1 1 2 '1' 3 1 1],[5 4 4 5 7 '10' 3 2 1],[3 1 1 1 2 '2' 3 1 1],[6 8 8 1 3 '4' 3 7 1],[4 1 1 3 2 '1' 3 1 1]]

X_test = [[3 1 1 1 2 '2' 3 1 1],[6 8 8 1 3 '4' 3 7 1]]
```

Elements of X_test are part of list X. Now, I want to find the index of every whole list of X_test within X.

```
For eg. X_test[0] is at the index 2 of X and X_test[1] at index 3.
```

Program should return the indexes of the matching lists. i.e `2 and 3`.

How can I do it in python? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both the `X` and `X_test` has syntax issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't quite run, as you need commas between the elements of each list.

So I've written my own example. This is what you can do:

```
X = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
X_test = [[4, 5, 6]]
for i in X_test:
    print(X.index(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res = []
for i in X_test:
    res.append(x.index(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.index()`:

```
indexes = [X.index(test) for test in X_test]
```

This whole thing is a bit clearer if you experiment with a simple list (rather than a list of lists):

```
>>> X = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> X_test = [9, 16]
>>> indexes = [X.index(test) for test in X_test]

[3, 4]
```